# Find the Fourier series for $\sin^8x+\cos^8x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

> Find the Fourier series for $f$:
>   $$
> f(x)=\sin^8x+\cos^8x
> $$

I tried to linearize $f(x)$ using the following formulas:
$$
\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i},\ \ \cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}
$$
And I got:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{256}\left((e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^8+(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^8\right)
$$
And now I'm stuck trying to calculate $a_0, a_n, b_n$:
$$
a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx,\ \ 
a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos nxdx,\ \ 
b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin nxdx
$$
So, I thought that there must be a better solution to this problem. Could someone tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you write $f$ as  a finite sum $\sum e^{ijx} a_j$ there is nothing more to be done since this sum is the (complex form of) Fourier series. The coefficents $a_j$ are already there when you expand you powers $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^{8}$ and $(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^{8}$. To get the real form of the Fourier series just write $e^{ijx} =\cos (jx)+i\sin (jx)$ and $e^{-ijx} =\cos (jx)-i\sin (jx)$. There is no need to evaluate any integrals.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&f(x)=\frac{1}{256}(2e^{8ix}+56e^{6ix-2ix}+140e^{4ix-4ix}+56e^{2ix-6ix}+2e^{-8ix})=\\
&=\frac{1}{128}(2\cos 8x+56\cos 4x+70)\\
&=\frac{35}{64}+\frac{7}{16}\cos4x+\frac{1}{64}\cos 8x
\end{aligned}
$$
Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

HInt:

$$(\cos^4x)^2+(\sin^4x)^2$$
$$=(\cos^4x-\sin^4x)^2+2\cos^4x\sin^4x$$

$$=(\cos2x)^2+\frac{(2\sin x\cos x)^4}8$$

$$=\dfrac{1+\cos4x}2+\dfrac{\sin^42x}8$$

Now $\sin^42x=\dfrac{(2\sin^22x)^2}4=\dfrac{(1-\cos4x)^2}4=\dfrac{1-2\cos4x+\cos^24x}4$

Finally $\cos^24x=\dfrac{1+\cos8x}2$